# failure to import pymongo ubuntu

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am currently runnning Ubuntu 12.04 with mongodb 2.2 and pymongo version 2.3.  I am attempting to gather some information using Twitters API and I am getting an error when attempting to import mymongo.  Here is what I have:

```
import pycurl, json
import pymongo


STREAM_URL = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json"
WORDS = "track=#obama"
USER = "myuser"
PASS = "mypass"
```

ImportError: No module named pymongo
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install it? If not try: `sudo apt-get install python-pymongo
`

Comment: Yes it is installed. I tried redoing the install and it is still giving me the same error.  Could it be that I am missing a dependency for pymongo to work?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python installed? Could it be installed for the *other* version?

Comment: I just checked to see which modules I have installed for python using pip freeze and it returned pymongo2.7- every module just has the name and version but for some reason pymongo has the dash after it.. could that mean anything?

Comment: Are you installing using `sudo apt-get install python python-pymongo` or are you using `sudo pip install pymongo`? I did a test on my local machine using `pip install pymongo` and had no issues.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Pymongo conflicts with the `bson` package. This worked for me:

```
sudo pip uninstall pymongo
sudo pip uninstall bson
sudo apt-get remove python-bson
sudo apt-get remove python-gridfs    # not sure if it's necessary
sudo pip install pymongo -U
```

Comment: after hours searching this was the solution that end up my nightmare!

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue and I installed it manually like this:

```
$ wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pymongo/pymongo-2.3.tar.gz
$ tar xzf pymongo-2.3.tar.gz
$ cd pymongo-2.3
$ python setup.py install
```

Works for me. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

cd /tmp/

wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/archive/master.zip

unzip master.zip

cd mongo-python-driver-master/

python setup.py install

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue. Easy way to do is install pip and install pymongo.

wget --no-check-certificate https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
python -m pip install pymongo