# import error: no module named bson

Tags: python, pymongo, bson

I'm trying to import `json_util` in my environment file:

```
from bson import json_util
```

I get this import error: `no module named bson`.

I tried to pip install and uninstall pymongo and bson - but nothing seemed to help. I found out that the bson package is included in pymongo so I installed it explicitly and then I received an `EPOCH_AWARE` import error.

Currently, only pymongo is installed. It works when I force the virtual environment by using this line:

```
#subprocess.Popen(['/home/.virtualenvs/simple_worker/bin/python', fileName])
```

But when I try to run it through the os like this:

```
os.system('PYTHON_ENV=%s python %s' % (env, fileName))
```

I get this import error on bson.

Edit: Here is the pip list output

```
(simple_worker) ➜ worker  pip list                                                                                         ✭ ✱
apache-libcloud (0.17.0)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.4.0.2)
gnureadline (6.3.3)
google-api-python-client (1.3.1)
httplib2 (0.9.2)
ipdb (0.8)
ipython (2.3.1)
mock (1.0.1)
oauth2client (1.5.1)
pbr (0.10.7)
pika (0.9.14)
pip (8.0.2)
psutil (2.2.0)
py (1.4.26)
pyaml (15.2.1)
pyasn1 (0.1.7)
pyasn1-modules (0.0.5)
pymongo (3.2.1)
pytest (2.6.4)
pytest-mock (0.4.0)
pytz (2015.4)
PyYAML (3.11)
redis (2.10.3)
requests (2.8.0)
rsa (3.1.4)
setuptools (11.0)
simplejson (3.6.5)
six (1.9.0)
stevedore (1.2.0)
uritemplate (0.6)
urllib3 (1.10)
virtualenv (12.0.7)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.5)
virtualenvwrapper (4.3.2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which OS are you running at? Did you try installing `bson` using pip as admin/super user? Are you working with virtualenv's or not? If so, did you activate it properly before running the code?

Comment: `PYTHON_ENV` is not a variable used by Python

Comment: what happens if you import bson on repl , what is the output of pip list?

Comment: @albert I'm runing on ubuntu. I tried installing bson using pip (as admin). I'm working with virtualenv and i activate it before pip install.

Comment: In your terminal try `pip freeze` in order to get a list of all 'pip-installed' packages and have a look whether `pymongo` is installed correctly.

Comment: Running ubuntu, installed with 'sudo pip install bson'.  That worked but there's no json_util in it.  I take you must use the version of bson in MongoDB to get json_util

Comment: @FabioCosta pip list added to the question

Comment: Did you install something `pymongo`-related using `apt`? There might be some incompatibilities: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16004833/3991125 http://www.openjems.com/pymongo-import-problem/ http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html

Answer (score 50):

If you **don't** get the `no module named bson` error but the `EPOCH_AWARE` import error , this is due to a **name clash between bson and pymongo** . In this case you should do these in order :

```
sudo pip uninstall bson
sudo pip uninstall pymongo
sudo pip install pymongo
```

you don't need to install bson again

Comment: tks, this error happened to me the same, supposed to use module pymongo instead of bson

Answer (score 2):

Please try on your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-bson
sudo apt-get install python-bson
```

Regards

Comment: Try also: `sudo apt-get purge python-pymongo`   then  `sudo apt-get install python-pymongo`

Comment: What about on windows?

Comment: Maybe 'pip install bson'

Answer (score 0):

I had used both `pymongo` and `bson` in my code, and I've had the same error `no module named bson`.
I first tried to install `bson` but it didn't work, so I uninstalled it again, then tried to re-install `pymongo` and it worked for me. I've used the following commands.
if you've installed `bson`, uninstall it:

```
pip uninstall bson
```

and uninstall then install `pymongo` again:

```
pip uninstall pymongo
pip install pymongo
```