# jupyter notebook - ImportError: No module named 'bson'

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter

Trying to play with some jupyter notebook, I have an issue with the bson module which seams not available as reported in the error: "ImportError: No module named 'bson'"

I'm running jupyter notebook 4.3.0 over a python 2.7 kernel which is available in a dedicated virtual environment. I tried to install manually the bson module through a simple "conda install bson" but it's not in the official/standard repo so I had to install OpenMDAO/bson. Finally, it didn't change the issue. I understand that the module might come from the pymongo package so I tried to install with the same result.

Any hint here? What's the link between bson and pymongo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can advise this answer: [import error: no module named bson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254975/import-error-no-module-named-bson)

Which states that:

> If you don't get the `no module named bson` error but the `EPOCH_AWARE import error`, this is due to a name clash between bson and pymongo.
>  
>   In this case, you should do these in order:

```
sudo pip uninstall bson
sudo pip uninstall pymongo
sudo pip install pymongo
```

In your case, try to start with a fresh virtualenv and do the above mentioned in the given order

That also answers the link between bson and pymongo.

Comment: Already seen that question and tested this. Tht'a why I created the question ;-). I didn't tried on a fresh virtualenv though.

Comment: Do that and comment if it goes as planed :)

Comment: Gave it another try and finally I got it to work by starting again from a fresh virtual env and triple checking this one was correctly installed within jupyter notebook with this http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs

Comment: Good to know mate :) Happy coding!